# 'distributed=true' property doesn't seem to work with ingest from query

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I am performing ingest from query in the following manner:-

```
.append async mytable with(distributed=true) <| myquery
```

Since this is using 'async' , I got an OperationId to track the progress. So when I issue `.show operations` command against the OperationsId , I get 2 rows in the resultset. The 'State' column value for both the rows was 'InProgress'. The 'NodeId' column value for one of the rows was blank whereas for the other row it was `KENGINE000001`. My cluster has 10+ worker nodes. Should I be getting ~ 10 rows as a result of this command , since I am using distribute=true option? And my data load is also heavy , so it's really a candidate for distributed ingestion. So either this property is not working or I am not interpreting its usage correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Should I be getting ~ 10 rows as a result of this command , since I am using distribute=true option?*

No

> So either this property is not working or I am not interpreting its usage correctly?

likely the latter, or a false expectation from the output of `.show operations`, see above.

you can track the state/status of an `async` command using `.show operations <operation_id>`

- If it doesn't reach a final state ("Completed","Failed","Throttled", etc.) after 1hr, that's unexpected - and you should open a support ticket for that.

regardless - it's ill-advised to attempt to ingest a lot of data (multi-GBs or more) using a single command, even if it's distributed.

- if that's what you're attempting to do, you should consider splitting your ingestion into multiple commands, each handling a subset of the data.
- see the 'remarks' section here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-from-query